# How to change the text my button displays?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web-applications

I'm creating a web app and can't seem to figure this out.

I have a button here:

```
  <form action="test" method="post" >
      <input type="Submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">
    </form>
```

When I test the code on my website, the button shows as follows:

[image]

How can I change the text of the button so that instead of it saying "Submit" it says "Home"? I've tried changing the name property of the button, but it still says "Submit".

I don't really know much about CSS and HTML, so if someone can walk me through on how to do this- that would be great.

Thanks :)

Comment: Use `value` attribute. This is really basic stuff, you should browse the internet for some course on HTML.

Comment: This is amazing problem .. I love this ... lolz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too easy to change your `input type button` name

use **`value` attribute in tag**

i added a spinet this makes things clear for you. :)

```html
<form action="test" method="post" >
      <input type="Submit" value="HOME" name="Submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">
    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks :) Works perfect!

Comment: happy to help you @ihoaxed

Answer (score 2):

```
<form action="test" method="post" >
   <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Home" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">
</form>
```

Home ---- > Change it to whatever you want

Answer (score 2):

You can use `value="your text here"` inside, as follow:

```
<input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="My Text Here" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">
```

Do not forget to add `/` for better coding:

```
<input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="My Text Here" class="btn btn-lg btn-default"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<form action="test" method="post" >
      <input type="Submit" value="Click Here" name="Submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned above, you have to set the value tag and that will be used as the display text. By default a submit button text is submit.

Alternatively, you can use javascript/jquery if you want to change the button text during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="test" method="post" >
<input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Click" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">
</form>
```

THe text of the button can be changed by value="watever"

Answer (score 1):

```
 <form action="test" method="post" >
      <input type="Submit" name="Submit" Value="Home" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">
    </form>
```

You can change via value atts